Equivalent definition of Riemann integrable function
Here is the definition of Riemann integrability used in my textbook: A function $f:[a, b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is Riemann integrable iff there eixsts some real number L such that $\forall \epsilon>0$, $\exists \delta>0$ such that for any tagged partition P with the norm $||P||< \delta$, then $|S(f; P) - L| < \epsilon$.
How to prove the following equivalent definition:
A function $f:[a, b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is Riemann integrable iff there eixsts some real number L such that $\forall \epsilon>0$, $\exists \delta > 0$ such that for any tagged partition P with the norm $||P|| \leq \delta$, then $|S(f; P) - L| \leq \epsilon$.

Is the two definition only different in "$\le\epsilon$" and "$<\epsilon$"? Then a hint is: if $a\le\frac\epsilon 2$ then $a<\epsilon$.

(Forward)
because $f$ is riemann integrable, there exist $I$ as the Riemann Integral of $f$ over $[a,b]$, such that for any $>0$, there exists a partition $$ of $[,]$ where the upper sum $(,)$ and the lower sum $(,)$ satisfy $(,)−(,)<$.

Choose $L = I$.

Because $I=\lim_{∥∥ \to 0} S(f;P)$ ,then it will get condition that Given $>0$, choose $>0$ such that for any tagged partition $$ with $∥∥≤$, the Riemann sum $(;)$ is close to $$.

It means the $|S(f;P)-I|$ will closer to $0$ so it satisfies the limit as the statement.
